# Function to modify a list of lists in order to prevent repeated numbers within sublists is not working completely

Tags: python, list, dataframe, function, sampling

Community of Stackoverflow:

I have a lists of sublists of sublists named dicts that was built by taken randomly from a df's index some values. The values can be repeated within the first level of the list of lists but not within the level of lists[e]. For example:

```
[[[40, 23, 29, 41, 42], [], [19, 17, 21, 20, 24]],    
 [[3, 9, 43, 44, 17], [], [20, 9, 23, 3, 27], [3, 30, 43]], #wrong because 9,3 and 43 are repeated in the three sublists
 [[2, 26, 42, 29, 44], [], [2, 3, 44, 31, 27]],  #2,44 are repeated
 [[31, 43, 32, 23, 33], [], [44, 9, 27, 23, 29]], #23 is repeated
 [[12, 27, 9, 44, 2], [], [25, 29, 40, 27, 12]]]  #27 repeated
```

As it can be seen, it doesn't matter if the number 3 is repeated in the second sublist of sublists and also in the third sublist of sublists. The empty lists don't matter.

I've built a function that "corrects" the repeating of those values but apparently it doesn't solve all the cases. It takes three arguments: the mentioned list of lists, the df where it takes the numbers (the df's index) called matrix and "cuantosamples" which is a list of lists that indicates how the final result will be partitioned (in uneven sized lists). It's important to note that the code also contains a segment that doesn't allow a value that is replacing a repeated value to be taken again to replace another value in the next sublist:

```
def vigilado(list1,matrix,cuantosamples):
    stored=[]
    lists=[[]for e in range(len(dicts))]
    vals=list(matrix.index.values)
    for e,g in zip(list1,lists):
        vig=list(itertools.chain(*e))
        dup=list(duplicates(vig))
        lendup=len(dup)
        if lendup>0:
            #assign new values
            vals=[e for e in vals if e not in dup and e not in vig and e not in stored] #si esta repetido en la sublista 1, que no vuelva atomar esos valores
            sample=matrix.loc[vals].sample(len(dup),weights='weights')
            vls=list(sample.index.values)
            #identify values to be replaced
            dups=[i for i, j in enumerate(vig) if j in dup]
            dups2=dups[lendup:]
            for i in range(len(dups2)):
                vig[dups2[i]]=vls[i]
        g.extend(vig)
        stored.extend(vig)
        
    l1=[[]for e in range(0,5)]
    for e,g,h in zip(lists,cuantosamples,l1):
        iterate=iter(e)
        l2=[list(islice(iterate,0,i))for i in g]
        h.extend(l2)
        
    return(l1)
    
vigilated=vigilado(dicts,matrix,cuantosamples)
vigilated
```

This return the following lists of lists, which as it can be seen, it works in mostly of the cases but not in all of them and I don't know why:

```
[[[40, 23, 29, 41, 42], [], [19, 17, 21, 20, 24]],
 [[3, 9, 43, 44, 17], [], [20, 9, 23, 16, 27], [33, 30, 14]], #3 and 43 are no longer repeated, BUT 9 IS STILL REPEATED
 [[2, 26, 42, 29, 44], [], [22, 3, 5, 31, 27]], #2 and 44 no longer repeated
 [[31, 43, 32, 23, 33], [], [44, 9, 27, 6, 29]], #23 no longer repeated
 [[12, 27, 9, 44, 2], [], [25, 29, 40, 1, 28]]] #27 no longer repeated
```

Can someone please help me? I don't have any idea of why the code is not applied to all cases because I thought that would solve it. Thanks.

Edit: this would be my desired output:

```
[[[40, 23, 29, 41, 42], [], [19, 17, 21, 20, 24]],
 [[3, 9, 43, 44, 17], [], [20, 10, 23, 16, 27], [33, 30, 14]],  #9 that wasn't replaced before is replaced here with a 10
 [[2, 26, 42, 29, 44], [], [22, 3, 5, 31, 27]], 
 [[31, 43, 32, 23, 33], [], [44, 9, 27, 6, 29]], 
 [[12, 27, 9, 44, 2], [], [25, 29, 40, 1, 28]]]
```

As you can see it's very similar to my resulting list (because my code somehows replaces almost all values but one or two). The change here was that I replaced the 9 of the lists[1][3] to 10.

Comment: Please re-read [ask] and make sure you understand that this is *not a discussion forum*. We don't want greetings and thanks; we do want clear, *specific* questions that remain after your best attempt to [find](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [isolate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) the problem.

Comment: "I've built a function that "corrects" the repeating of those values" *What does that actually mean*? For the given input, exactly what should the output be, and why?

Comment: "sample=matrix.loc[vals].sample(len(dup),weights='weights')" Did you consider the possibility that, when picking randomly sampled values to replace the duplicates, it coincidentally chooses the same number again?

Comment: IT ISN'T A DISCUSSION FORUM. It's a very clear QUESTION where I want to know why my function isn't working. The second thing that you put, I was referring that my function is supposed to work but it didn't. The third thing: "vals" list was intended to avoid the selection of previous selected values, and it didn't worked. I will put my desired output because I think that's the only thing missing

Comment: "The second thing that you put, I was referring that my function is supposed to work but it didn't." This doesn't help. Of course, *every* code "is supposed to work", or we would not write it. "I will put my desired output because I think that's the only thing missing" This does help, but what you are still missing: try to figure out, by yourself, why the problem occurs - by carefully tracing through the logic of the code, step by step. Check the values that variables have at each point in the process. Where does it differ from your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

My response does not point out where the problem of your code is, but two approaches to your goal.

**Approach 1**

Generate `dicts` that does not have repeated index within each list of `dicts`. Explanations in code.

```
import numpy as np

index = np.arange(100)
cuantosamples = [[5, 0, 5], [5, 0, 5, 3], [5, 0, 5], [5, 0, 5], [5, 0, 5]]

np.random.seed(0)

dicts = [
    list(map(list, # convert np.array to list
        np.split( # split a list into sublists
            np.random.choice(index, sum(needs), replace=False), # generate random choices without replacement
            np.cumsum(needs)[:-1] # how to split
        )))
    for needs in cuantosamples
]
# print(dicts)
```

**Approach 2**

Replace repeated values with new values. Explanations in code.

```
dicts = [
    [[40, 23, 29, 41, 42], [], [19, 17, 21, 20, 24]],    
    [[3, 9, 43, 44, 17], [], [20, 9, 23, 3, 27], [3, 30, 43]], 
    [[2, 26, 42, 29, 44], [], [2, 3, 44, 31, 27]],  
    [[31, 43, 32, 23, 33], [], [44, 9, 27, 23, 29]],
    [[12, 27, 9, 44, 2], [], [25, 29, 40, 27, 12]]
]

np.random.seed(0)

new_dicts = []
for lists, needs in zip(dicts, cuantosamples):
    ary = np.array([x for l in lists for x in l ]) # flatten lists into an array
    candidates = [x for x in index if x not in ary] # find out what to be replaced with
    values, counts = np.unique(ary, return_counts=True) # find out what to replace
    
    for v, c in zip(values, counts - 1):
        if c:
            ary[ary==v] = np.concatenate([[v], np.random.choice(candidates, c, replace=False)]) #replace
            
    new_dicts.append(list(map(list, np.split(ary, np.cumsum(needs)[:-1]))))
    
new_dicts
```